# Update MS Access table empty fields based on same table

Tags: ms-access, sql-update, is-empty

In MS Access database, I'm working with a table that has rows. In some cases not all columns of the rows are filled. I want to create an update query to update the values of the empty fields with data from other rows where the column is not empty.

googled the question but no satisfying answer has been found. Can someone show me how the query should be build?

Current table looks like

```
| Invoicenumber | Customer | Date    |
|---------------|----------|---------|
| 5             | 12       | 12-6-19 |
| 5             |          | 12-6-19 |
| 5             |          | 12-6-19 |
| 5             |          | 12-6-19 |
| 6             | 18       | 15-6-19 |
| 6             |          | 15-6-19 |
| 6             |          | 15-6-19 |
| 7             | 20       | 20-6-19 |
| 7             |          | 20-6-19 |
```

I need the table to look like this after updating:

```
| Invoicenumber | Customer | Date    |
|---------------|----------|---------|
| 5             | 12       | 12-6-19 |
| 5             | 12       | 12-6-19 |
| 5             | 12       | 12-6-19 |
| 5             | 12       | 12-6-19 |
| 6             | 18       | 15-6-19 |
| 6             | 18       | 15-6-19 |
| 6             | 18       | 15-6-19 |
| 7             | 20       | 20-6-19 |
| 7             | 20       | 20-6-19 |
```

Comment: [Format table data](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Your  data looks like empty fields are invoicepositions joined with invoices  and there where two tables invoices with number, customer and invoicepositions  with the number, but not the customer. are there more columns?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher there are many more columns but those are unrelated to the problem. I will update my question with one more column so it looks closer to the real data.

Comment: What is purpuse of having a table with duplicate values. Your data is a result of a query betwen at leasr two tables and there should be a field that is unequal to the combination of invoicenumber and customer.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher, again sorry for the not clear example. There are a lot more columns with data. In those columns, the data is different per row for the same invoicenumber, so unique rows exist.

Comment: Don't you want to have the original data structure, There should be customers table, but the question is, what is the question? Means what do you want to do with the data? If you extract the tables, you can create a query that fills the data without any update and any update means a new duplicate value. But that would be somewhat exaggerated if you just want to print this;)

Comment: This will require VBA manipulating recordset. Also need some unique identifier field(s) that can properly order records. That is not shown in sample data. Data structure is not normalized. Should be Invoices and InvoiceDetails tables. CustomerId would be foreign key saved in Invoices where InvoiceID is unique primary key and InvoiceID saved as foreign key in InvoiceDetails. Then UPDATE would not be needed.

Comment: @June7, I'm open to the idea of using VBA. Can you show me some leads on how to proceed with that? There is a unique identifier field in the data table. This data is imported from a data source that can only provide this format. The lines where customer is filled, contain total sums of the invoices. Those however lack certain details and will be removed later from the table. Before removing, the customer need to be copied to the connected invoice lines. It is what it is, hoping to have a valid solution. Kind regards.

Comment: Ooops, backtrack on my comment. There is a way to do this with query alone using DLookup().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with just SQL by joining the table to itself:

```
UPDATE 
    Invoices 
    INNER JOIN Invoices AS Inv2
    ON Invoices.InvoiceNumber = Inv2.InvoiceNumber
SET
    Invoices.Customer = Inv2.Customer
WHERE 
    (Invoices.[Customer] Is Null)
    AND (Inv2.Customer IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Nice, without distinct or aggregates the query stays updateable.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a Switch statement into the update to choose the value to update based on the state of the CUSTOMER field.

```
Update TestTable 
Set CUSTOMER = Switch(CUSTOMER is  Null,OTHER_FIELD,CUSTOMER = '',OTHER_FIELD,CUSTOMER<>'',CUSTOMER)
```

This statement will update the CUSTOMER field to the OTHER_FIELD where CUSTOMER is blank or CUSTOMER is Null.  If CUSTOMER has a value, it sets it to that value (essentially leaving it as the same.)

The 'SWITCH' statement is Access's version of a 'Switch' or 'Select Case' in code, where the first parameter is the condition to check, the parameter after it is the value to take if the previous condition returns true.  So...

```
Switch(1=1,'YES',2=1,'NO', case 3, return 3, case 4, return 4, etc., etc.,)
```

would return the 'YES' because 1 is equal to 1.

There would be a more eloquent way to do this with code, but in an Access query, I don't know any other way.

Comment: @RunningThruLife, thank you for you answer. You mean VBA code? Because that is also an option for me. Can you show me some leads on how to proceed on that?

Comment: I did mean VBA code, but as I said, it's not _necessary_.  The code would depend on a couple of things.  In your question, you asked for an SQL Query in Access to handle it.  If you need code to do the same, that'd be a different question I think.  Does this solve the original problem?

Comment: Not seeing how this will populate Customer field with appropriate Customer ID.

Comment: June, OP said he was looking to update values in one row where the column is blank from another column where it is not.  The switch will take the value from the other field where the customer field has no value.  Am I misunderstanding something in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using domain aggregate function to pull the Customer:

```
UPDATE table1 SET table1.Customer = DMax("Customer","table1","Invoicenumber=" & [Invoicenumber])
WHERE (((table1.Customer) Is Null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Question answered by solution mentioned by @John Mo. Used his code to update table with data available within the table.